# Making legend on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How can I add a legend to this code?

Thanks!

```
ggplot()+ 
  geom_point(data=avg_harv_df, aes(x=samp_per, y=ndvi), size=3, color='red') + 
  geom_point(data=avg_sjer_df, aes(x=samp_per, y=ndvi), size=3, color='blue') +
  ylab("NDVI")+
  xlab("Sampling period")
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
ggplot()+ 
  geom_point(data=avg_harv_df, aes(x=samp_per, y=ndvi, col = "a"), size=3) + 
  geom_point(data=avg_sjer_df, aes(x=samp_per, y=ndvi, col = "b"), size=3) +
  ylab("NDVI")+
  xlab("Sampling period")
```

Option 2:

```
combined <- dplyr::bind_rows(avg_harv_df, avg_sjer_df, .id = 'col')
ggplot(combined, aes(x=samp_per, y=ndvi, col = col))+ 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  ylab("NDVI")+
  xlab("Sampling period")
```

I almost always prefer option 2.

Comment: Thanks, Axeman! Now I have my legend, but what if I want to name my legend with something different other than colour (site, for example)?